# Serverless deploy throws exception: `can't combine user with prefix, exec_prefix/home, or install_(plat)base`

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, serverless

I'm trying to set up a `serverless` application using AWS lambda. The app uses boto3 and firebase. I added a firebase private key file and added AWS credentials to serverless. But when I run `serverless deploy`, I get this error:

```
STDERR: ERROR: Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 188, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 407, in run
      use_user_site=options.use_user_site,
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 58, in install_given_reqs
      **kwargs
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 928, in install
      use_user_site=use_user_site, pycompile=pycompile,
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 461, in move_wheel_files
      warn_script_location=warn_script_location,
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/wheel.py", line 326, in move_wheel_files
      prefix=prefix,
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations.py", line 111, in distutils_scheme
      i.finalize_options()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 252, in finalize_options
      raise DistutilsOptionError("can't combine user with prefix, "
  distutils.errors.DistutilsOptionError: can't combine user with prefix, exec_prefix/home, or install_(plat)base

      at /home/ludwig/Dev/[PROJECT]/node_modules/serverless-python-requirements/lib/pip.js:320:13
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at installRequirements (/home/ludwig/Dev/[PROJECT]/node_modules/serverless-python-requirements/lib/pip.js:307:28)
      at installRequirementsIfNeeded (/home/ludwig/Dev/[PROJECT]/node_modules/serverless-python-requirements/lib/pip.js:532:3)
      at ServerlessPythonRequirements.installAllRequirements (/home/ludwig/Dev/[PROJECT]/node_modules/serverless-python-requirements/lib/pip.js:611:29)
      at ServerlessPythonRequirements.tryCatcher (/home/ludwig/Dev/[PROJECT]/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
      at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/ludwig/Dev/[PROJECT]/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:517:31)
      at Promise._settlePromise (/home/ludwig/Dev/[PROJECT]/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:574:18)
      at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/ludwig/Dev/[PROJECT]/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:619:10)
      at Promise._settlePromises (/home/ludwig/Dev/[PROJECT]/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:699:18)
      at _drainQueueStep (/home/ludwig/Dev/[PROJECT]/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
      at _drainQueue (/home/ludwig/Dev/[PROJECT]/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
      at Async._drainQueues (/home/ludwig/Dev/[PROJECT]/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
      at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/ludwig/Dev/[PROJECT]/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)
      at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:131:23)
```

I tried executing `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, but it didn't solve the problem.

I use Manjaro Linux 18.1 (Arch Linux) with KDE. Docker is enabled and running.

This is the first time I use `serverless`, so I'm sorry if I'm doing something stupid. The other developers in my team don't have any issues with the project, they don't know what this error means either. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3826 This looks like it'll fix your issue (use --system)
Also the linked debian bug - it appears to be fixed in the latest version of PIP, however it could've reappeared - https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=830892

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Note that I use Manjaro (based on Arch Linux), not Debian.

Comment: I fixed it now. The problem was an incorrect AWS key. I don't understand why it caused this particular, weird error message, though.

Comment: for me i had to upgrade the npm version of `serverless-python-requirements`